# Calculate standard deviation with only the averages from a number of samples

Tags: standard-deviation

I am trying to estimate the standard deviation of a population based on 100 samples each with 1,000,000 data points. I have been told it is acceptable to do this using only the average from each of the 100 samples (rather than using all 100,000,000 data points), but it seems to me that this would be quite inaccurate.

My question is, is this a reasonable way to estimate the population standard deviation and, if so, what is the correct formula to use? Are there any adjustments that need to be made?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Absolutely not, averages are much less variable than raw data. Maybe it could help if you give us some context of the problem, what this data represents.

Comment: What do you mean by "100 samples with 1Mio data points"? Are these 100 vectors from a feature space with a dimension of 1Mio? Or the other way around? Or yet something else?

Comment: Do you mean you'll get 100 samples, calculate the standard deviation in each of them, and then average these standard deviation values together?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To proceed in general, suppose we have $n$ samples that each contain $m$ values, generated as IID variables from an underlying superpopulation with mean parameter $\mu$ and standard deviation parameter $\sigma$.  Now, suppose we define the quantities:

$$\bar{X}_k \equiv \frac{1}{m} \sum_{j=1}^m X_{k,j}
\quad \quad \quad 
\bar{X}_* \equiv \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \bar{X}_k
\quad \quad \quad 
S_{*}^2 \equiv \frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{i=1}^n (\bar{X}_k - \bar{X}_*)^2.$$

The values $\bar{X}_k$ are the sample means of the individual samples $k=1,...,n$ and the values $\bar{X}_*$ and $S_*^2$ are the sample mean and sample variance of the set of sample means.  Using standard moment rules, it can easily be shown that:

$$\mathbb{E}(\bar{X}_k) = \mu
\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad 
\mathbb{V}(\bar{X}_k) = \frac{\sigma^2}{m}
\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad 
\mathbb{E}(S_*^2) = \frac{\sigma^2}{m}.$$

Consequently, you can obtain an estimator for the standard deviation parameter as $\hat{\sigma} = \sqrt{m} \cdot S_*$.  This estimator is biased, but it can be bias-corrected if you want (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Unbiased_sample_standard_deviation)), based on the normality of the sample means (by appeal to the CLT).  The bias-corrected estimator is:

$$\hat{\sigma}_\text{UB} = \sqrt{\frac{(n-1)m}{2}} \cdot \frac{\Gamma(\tfrac{n-1}{2})}{\Gamma(\tfrac{n}{2})} \cdot S_*.$$

In your problem you have $n=100$ and $m=1000000$ which gives the unbiased estimator:

$$\hat{\sigma}_\text{UB} = \sqrt{49500000} \cdot \frac{\Gamma(49.5)}{\Gamma(50)} \cdot S_* = 1002.528 \cdot S_*.$$

Comment: Thanks very much Ben, this is very helpful! This isn't the approach I've been told to use and it gives a lower result for the standard deviation. I was wondering if you'd mind giving your opinion on the approach suggested to me, where it might have come from and how good an estimator it produces. The approach is as follows: Calculate standard deviation of the set of sample means using Excel's SDEV.S function (which divides by n rather than n-1). Divide result by square root of m.

Comment: That will give you a terrible estimate (that is six orders of magnitude from the correct value).  You should be *multiplying* by $\sqrt{m}$, not dividing.  Remember that the bigger $m$ is, the *less* variable are the observed sample means, so you scale them *upward* to correct this.  (Dividing by $n$ or $n-1$ for the sample variance is not going to make a huge difference here.)

Comment: Sorry yes, multiplying is what I meant to say, my mistake! Does this give an estimate that's comparable in accuracy to what you suggested above?

Comment: That is almost the same here --- it would give $\hat{\sigma} = 1000 \cdot S_*$.